# Scrolling to left on a webelement in selenium when the scroll bar can not be reached

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to run testing using a Selenium Webdriver, I am fairly new but I am writing in C# so it is familiar. In order to test I am grabbing text values from a table to compare them to the known values I am using. It is working for all of the visible columns but I need to reach columns to the left that are being virtualized, so their text isn't reachable unless the column is on the screen. Because I am unable to get into the web code to undo the virtualization I just want to scroll to the left. The problem is that there isn't a scroll element I can reach and I am not scrolling through the whole page, just the webelement holding the table. I have tried a few different ways but can't seem to get it working.

As of right now I going about it by using JQuery and a Javascript executor but this isn't scrolling (assume the driver is set up and going to the correct place)

```
string script = "$'argument[0].scrollLeft(200)";
IJavaScriptExecutor JExec = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
var view = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".ngGrid"));
JExecute.ExecuteScript(script, view);
```

I have also tried

```
JExecute.ExecuteScript("$'argument[0].scrollLeft(200)", view);
```

and

```
JExecute.ExecuteScript("view.scrollBy(-200, 0)");
```

Comment: how about `JExecute.ExecuteScript("window.scrollBy(0,-200)");`

Comment: If you are not able to scroll but you are getting the target element..then you can try to perform action that element using JavaScript...

Comment: How does the user scroll left when they want to? Is there a link or button or ? that they click?